# How to fix onResume/onRestart fullscreen ad?

Tags: android, fullscreen, ads, onresume

I'm trying to insert a full-screen ad, following the guide provided by my network. 
this is [the guide](http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/android.html)

**and this is my code**

```
private RevMob revmob;
private RevMobFullscreen fullscreen;

protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.episodi_activity);

    revmob = RevMob.start(this);
    fullscreen = revmob.createFullscreen(this, null);
}
protected void onRestart [or onResume :)] () {
    super.onRestart ();
    fullscreen.show ();
}
```

the full-screen ad work but only for the first onRestart or onResume, subsequent ones, nothing happens. 
How can I solve this problem? (show full-screen to "every" time start the onRestart or onResume methods.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Used this code successfully.
In oncreate used the following code

```
    revmob = RevMob.start(this, "your ad id");
    revmob.printEnvironmentInformation(this);
    revmob.setTestingMode(RevMobTestingMode.WITH_ADS);
    revmob.createFullscreen(this, revmobListener);
    revmob.showFullscreen(this);
    revmob.setTimeoutInSeconds(5);
```

and used the following method

```
public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
          revmobListener = new RevMobAdsListener() {
         @Override
         public void onRevMobAdDisplayed() {
             Log.i("[RevMob]", "onAdDisplayed");
         }

     @Override
     public void onRevMobAdReceived() {
         Log.i("[RevMob]", "onAdReceived");

     }

     @Override
     public void onRevMobAdNotReceived(String message) {
         Log.i("[RevMob]", "onAdNotReceived");
     }

     @Override
     public void onRevMobAdDismiss() {
         Log.i("[RevMob]", "onAdDismiss");
     }

     @Override
     public void onRevMobAdClicked() {
         Log.i("[RevMob]", "onAdClicked");
     }
 };
}

public void showFullscreen(View view) {
 RevMobFullscreen fs = revmob.createFullscreen(this, revmobListener);
 fs.show();

}
```

This Code worked fine for me.